# adding form validation jquery causes previous jquery submit function not to work

Tags: php, jquery

i have a form which stops behaving as expected when i add form validation jquery.

```
<form class="myform" action="booking.php?token=<?php echo time(); ?>" method="get" name="f<?php echo ( $row['vehicle_id'] );?>" class="request_submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="v_id" value="<?php echo ( $row['vehicle_id'] );?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p_id" value="<?php echo $params['quote_location']['pickup']['location_id']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p_val" value="<?php echo $params['quote_location']['pickup']['location_name']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="d_id" value="<?php echo $params['quote_location']['dropp']['location_id']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="d_val" value="<?php echo $params['quote_location']['dropp']['location_name']; ?>" />                     
<?php
    if (  $row['vehicle_price_mode'] == 'fixed' ):
        $v_price = $row['vehicle_price'] ;
    else:
        $v_price = ( $params['quote_price'] * $row['vehicle_price'] ) / 100 ;
    endif;

?>
<div style="padding:15px;">
    <table style="width:200px;border:0px solid black">
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <div class="quoteradio">
                <label><input name="q_price" type="radio" checked="checked" value="oneway|<?php echo swd_number_format(  ( $params['quote_price'] + $v_price )); ?>"> One Way: &pound;<?php echo (  swd_number_format(  $params['quote_price'] + $v_price  ) ); ?></label>
            </div>  
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <div class="quoteradio">
                <label><input name="q_price" type="radio" value="twoway|<?php echo swd_number_format(  ( $params['quote_price'] + $v_price ) * 2 ); ?>"> Two Way: &pound;<?php echo swd_number_format(  ( $params['quote_price'] + $v_price ) * 2 ) ; ?></label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">                      <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">RESERVE </button></td>
    </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
```

which is linked to a submit action

```
$(".myform").submit(function(e){
    var targeted_popup_class = "popup-1";
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

    e.preventDefault();
    var vehicle_id = $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"][name="v_id"]').val();
    $('input[name="vehicle_id"]').val(vehicle_id);
    var pickup_id = $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"][name="p_id"]').val();
    $('input[name="pickup_id"]').val(pickup_id);    
    var pickup_name = $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"][name="p_val"]').val();
    $('input[name="pickup_name"]').val(pickup_name);
    var dest_id = $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"][name="d_id"]').val();
    $('input[name="dest_id"]').val(dest_id);
    var dest_name = $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"][name="d_val"]').val();
    $('input[name="dest_name"]').val(dest_name);
    var quote_price = $(this).parent().find('input[type="radio"][name="q_price"]:checked').val();
    $('input[name="quote_price"]').val(quote_price);
});
```

but when i try to include form validationon the same page for a different form 
my initial submit jquery stops behaving as expected

just adding this jquery tax above my previous jquery stops it functioning as expected

```
      $("form[name='registration']").validate({

    }
  });
```

. please advise why and how i can solve this.

Thanks

Comment: $("form[name='registration']").validate({

Comment: Do you get console errors? If so, what?

Comment: I also noticed you have two `class` attributes, which is invalid html, on your form you posted. You need to have that be `class="myform request_submit"`